# Static class in C++

Tags: c++, class, static

In the header I declared

```
#ifndef SOUND_CORE
#define SOUND_CORE

static SoundEngine soundEngine;

...
```

but the constructor for SoundEngine gets called multiple times, how is it possible, when it's declared as global static

I call it as

```
#include "SoundCore.h"
```

and use it directly

```
soundEngine.foo()
```

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `extern` instead of static. That's what `extern` is for.

In the header:

```
extern SoundEngine soundEngine;
```

In an accompanying source file:

```
SoundEngine soundEngine;
```

This will create one translation unit with the instance, and including the header will allow you to use it everywhere in your code.

```
// A.cpp
#include <iostream>
// other includes here
...
extern int hours; // this is declared globally in B.cpp

int foo()
{
hours = 1;
}


// B.cpp
#include <iostream>
// other includes here
...
int hours; // here we declare the object WITHOUT extern
extern void foo(); // extern is optional on this line

int main()
{
foo();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A copy of static variables declared in header files gets created for each translation unit where you include the header.
Never declare your static variables inside header files.

You could use a [**singleton**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object.

Comment: yes, static is per translation unit. The remedy would be a Singleton or the like.

Comment: stupid me was thinking: Can you do 'extern SoundEngine soundEngine' and then implement in one compilation unit as static(that is, without the extern keyword)?

Comment: @Mario The Spoon: Yes you can do that and it is perfectly valid and will work, but as a matter of personal choice i really don't like to use extern in that way.

Comment: Both singletons and `extern` objects have issues (both from a design point of view, and from the way they work in C++). My preferred approach is to instantiate the object inside a function (`main()` or something similarly high in the call chain), and pass a reference (or possibly a smart pointer, depending on how complicated the objects' lifetimes are) to everything that needs it.

Comment: @Mike, @Als: well, if the application needs a true global configuration/storage object, why not make it global (inside a namespace)? The only issue I can see with this, is threading, but that can be helped by using the correct threading idioms either enforced outside of the object, or hidden inside of the global/static.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: True, but If the call chain is just too long, then one might be forced to use `global` or `static`. `Singetons` or `Global` or `Static` each have their own pros and cons, the decision to go for which one, sure needs a lot of consideration.

Comment: @rubenvb: static objects with external linkage (i.e. objects declared `extern` at namespace scope) expose you to the initialisation order fiasco. If you only have one, or if all your globals are in the same translation unit, then you're fine. Otherwise, you can get bugs where initialising an object in one translation unit requires one in another translation unit to be initialised, but there is no way to enforce the initialisation order. This can be partly solved by changing them to static objects at function scope, but then you have threading and destruction-order issues.

Comment: @Als: How can a call chain be "too long" to pass a parameter through it? Function arguments don't expire if they're passed too far. Or do you just mean that adding a parameter to many functions seems like a lot of work, when making a global object requires less typing?

Comment: @Mike Seymour: By "too long" I mean passing down the variables through too many functions which actually dont really use it, Also, It adds a undue risk of unitnetionally modifying the variable in this long flow.

Comment: @Mike: when you have 2 or 3 steps of classes that pass an "unused" parameter around, it might be confusing. Or if literally every class or function needs it, you wonder why it's just not there to use, and have to pass it explicitely.

Comment: @rubenvb: It will be clear that it's not unused, since you can clearly see it being passed on to other functions. If it really is used literally everywhere, then yes, there is a case for making it globally accessible; however, the advantages of less typing, and less clutter in function interfaces, must be weighed against the disadvantages of a less clear dependency structure, less flexibility to add multiple instances later (even if you currently believe that you will only ever need a single interface), and less control over object lifetimes.

Comment: ("single interface" should read "single instance" in the previous comment)

Comment: @Mike: Yeah, ok, I understand what you're trying to say. It's certainly a valid point I agree with. Thanks for taking the time to elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned in the answers, `static` variable in header file gets included in every file where the the header is included. If you want to still keep it `static` and avoid multiple instantiations then wrap it in a `struct`.

```
//SoundCore.h
struct Wrap {
  static SoundEngine soundEngine;
};
```

Now define this variable in one of the `.cpp` files.

```
//SoundCore.cpp
SoundEngine Wrap::soundEngine;
```

And use it simply as,

```
Wrap::soundEngine.foo();
```

Comment: Why would you want to wrap it in a class rather than declaring it `extern` at namespace scope?

Comment: @Mike, actually `extern` is the best idea for such single variables. Since @rubenvb already suggested the same; I gave this another way (saying `if you still want to keep it static`).

Comment: you're not "keeping it static" in any way other than preserving the `static` keyword, which has a different meaning in this context. This is precisely equivalent to making it `extern` (i.e. it changes the linkage from internal to external), but with an extra layer of confusion caused by introducing a meaningless class.

Answer (score 0):

If you include this header file in multiple files, your class will be instantiated for every inclusion. I think you better take a look at Singleton pattern, to get only 1 instance, i.e., just one constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

As many other reserved words, static is a modifier that has different meanings according with the context.

In this case, you are creating an object of the class SoundEngine which is private in this module. This means that it is not visible from other modules.

However, you put this line in the header, so it is a private object in various modules. I guess  that's the reason of the constructor being called multiple times.